# convert SQL join query to pyspark syntax

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working to convert a known working SQL query to work in pyspark, given two dataframes, using methods such as: `.join`, `.where`, `filter`, etc.

Here are examples of SQL queries that work (only selecting `r.id` where I will normally select more columns):

```
# "invalid" records, where there is a matching `record_id` for rv_df
SELECT DISTINCT(r.id) FROM core_record AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN core_recordvalidation rv ON r.id = rv.record_id WHERE r.job_id = 41 AND rv.record_id is not null;

# "valid" records, where there is no matching `record_id` for rv_df
SELECT DISTINCT(r.id) FROM core_record AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN core_recordvalidation rv ON r.id = rv.record_id WHERE r.job_id = 41 AND rv.record_id is not null;
```

I'm 80/20 close, but having trouble wrapping my head around the the last few steps, and/or how to do this most efficiently.

I've got a Dataframe `r_df` with column `id` that I'd like to join with Dataframe `rv_df` on column `record_id`.  As output, I'd like only **distinct** `r.id`, and only columns from `r_df`, none from `rv_df`.  Finally, I'd like two different calls where there **is** a match (what will be "invalid" records for me), and where there is **not** a match (what I consider "valid" records).

I have pyspark queries that get close, but not terribly clear on how to ensure that `r_df.id` is distinct, and select only columns from `r_df`, none from `rv_df`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Both queries in your question look the same to me. Translating it to DataFrame functions would be: `invalid_df = r_df.alias('r').join(rv_df.withColumn('record_id', f.col('id')).alias('rv'), on='id', how='left_outer').where('(r.job_id = 41) AND (rv.record_id is not null)').select('r.id').distinct()`. Based on the [docs for `join`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html): *the column(s) must exist on both sides*, which is why I created an `id` column on `rv_df`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to walk away for a couple hours.  Found a solution that works for my use case.

First, selecting only distinct `record_id` from `rv_df`:

```
rv_df = rv_df.select('record_id').distinct()
```

Then use that for intersection and disjoints:

```
# Intersection:
j_df = r_df.join(rv_df, r_df.id == rv_df.record_id, 'leftsemi').select(r_df['*'])

# Disjoint:
j_df = r_df.join(rv_df, r_df.id == rv_df.record_id, 'leftanti').select(r_df['*'])
```